# Is there a way to create string literal union type from and object in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

`const FOO_TYPES={ FOO:'foo', FAA:'faa' }`

I want to use the object above to programmatically create the following type:

`type FooTypes = "foo" | "faa"`

So that typescript can throw and error if a value other than the specified ones is provided.

I have a similar thing where I get the type from the object like so:

`type ObjectValues<T>=T[keyof T]`

But in this case TypeScript will only expect the type and not check for the allowed values.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVbAqN) might be what you're looking for.  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change how you initialize `FOO_TYPES`.  In your version:

```
const FOO_TYPES = { FOO: 'foo', FAA: 'faa' };
/* const FOO_TYPES: {
    FOO: string;
    FAA: string;
} */
```

the compiler infers the type `{FOO: string, FAA: string}` for that variable.  This is often what people want when they initialize a variable, since someone might reasonably want to assign other `string` values to the properties, like `FOO_TYPES.FAA='blah';`. But that's not what you want here; in the above type, the compiler has forgotten the specific [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"foo"` and `"faa", and there's no way to recover them.  So if you want the compiler to remember these types, you need to *prevent* it from widening.

An easy way to get that behavior is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializer:

```
const FOO_TYPES = { FOO: 'foo', FAA: 'faa' } as const;
/* const FOO_TYPES: {
    readonly FOO: "foo";
    readonly FAA: "faa";
} */
```

This tells the compiler that you plan to treat `FOO_TYPES` like a somewhat immutable data type, where the properties will not change after being set.  And it infers a narrower type for each value, including the `"foo"` and `"faa"` literal types you want.

---

Once you do that it's straightforward to define `FooTypes` in terms of the [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) `FOO_TYPES`:

```
type FooTypes = ObjectValues<typeof FOO_TYPES>; 
// type FooTypes = "foo" | "faa"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgeQQfQCoE0AKBRAysgBhgF4YBveJALhgHIAzEEWgGngEF2aGBDH2mAF8A3AFgAUAHoAVDFCRYiFBhz4CNMhJjbKCGtABOASzABzMeJ0cuMQyfMTBMaZIkT50XWix4S5XdyMzGxwnIF8Ak48EHLg0BYysQpeKngaWjoGAKY8ACbgADYAngEwAERBZRZW2XmFJaE2FXxVjs6u4hJQRQAOWTAIAEYAVlnAUABqPAUArlkQADyoAHx+qADaANZZRSD0MKgAuhZdvf1wTKhnMaRDo+NTs-ML3X17KT64ywmSMK-nl2ufgqTDKMAAPuV6C0gA)